# Draw path from ArrayList doesn't work

Tags: android

My app force to close when I'm trying to draw a path while I'm moving my finger on the screen. The code start to draw some of the lines in the path, but then it force to close down. What have I done wrong?

The OnTouchListener in MainActivity class:

```
    @Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction()) {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        gameLoop.touchDownX = event.getX();
        gameLoop.touchDownY = event.getY();
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        Point point = new Point();
        point.x = (int) event.getX();
        point.y = (int) event.getY();
        gameLoop.addPoints(point);
        gameLoop.startDrawLine = true;
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        gameLoop.touchUpX = event.getX();
        gameLoop.touchUpY = event.getY();
        gameLoop.touchActionUp = true;
        break;
    }

    return true; 
}
```

The draw method inside GameLoop class:

```
    // Method to draw objects
private void drawObjects(Canvas canvas) {

    // Clear screen with black color
    canvas.drawRGB(0, 0, 0);

    // Draw line
    if(startDrawLine) {

        // Set properties to Paint object
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);

        // Draw path
        path.moveTo(touchDownX, touchDownY);

        for(Point point: points) {
            path.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
            canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        }
        path.reset();
    }
```

LogCat info:

```
04-28 11:54:23.155: W/dalvikvm(2896): threadid=10: thread exiting with uncaught  exception (group=0x40018578)
04-28 11:54:23.155: E/AndroidRuntime(2896): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-11
04-28 11:54:23.155: E/AndroidRuntime(2896): java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
04-28 11:54:23.155: E/AndroidRuntime(2896):     at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:576)
04-28 11:54:23.155: E/AndroidRuntime(2896):     at com.androidTest.mergemania.GameLoop.drawObjects(GameLoop.java:251)
04-28 11:54:23.155: E/AndroidRuntime(2896):     at com.androidTest.mergemania.GameLoop.run(GameLoop.java:216)
04-28 11:54:23.155: E/AndroidRuntime(2896):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Comment: Where are you calling `drawObjects`?

Comment: The exception indicates you're modifying the collection of points from multiple threads at the same time. You'll need to synchronize access to the collection in such a way that no modifications can be made from one thread while another is iterating over its contents. You may want to give [`Collections.synchronizedList(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%3CT%3E%29) a go.

Comment: I'm calling the drawObjects from the run() method between canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(); and surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that all code in drawObjects? LogCat tells us you are modifying list while iterating over it. I'd expect you have a code like this that breaks:

```
    for(Point point: points) {
        path.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        points.remove(point); // this line added
    }
```

**Edit:**

Oh, you are probably using `SurfaceView` and drawing in a separate thread. In that case you need to synchronize calls to list of points. Maybe use a `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.

And please read about threading on [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html).

**Edit2:**

Something like this should work, but I really would not use it in production code, as it blocks threads. You need to have a really small amount of code (in terms of execution time) for threads to work efficiently. (4 lines added, commented with `this line added`).

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

synchronized (gameLoop) { // this line added

switch (event.getAction()) {

case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    gameLoop.touchDownX = event.getX();
    gameLoop.touchDownY = event.getY();
    break;

case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    Point point = new Point();
    point.x = (int) event.getX();
    point.y = (int) event.getY();
    gameLoop.addPoints(point);
    gameLoop.startDrawLine = true;
    break;

case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    gameLoop.touchUpX = event.getX();
    gameLoop.touchUpY = event.getY();
    gameLoop.touchActionUp = true;
    break;
}

} // this line added

return true; 
}
```

and this:

```
// Method to draw objects
private void drawObjects(Canvas canvas) {

synchronized (this) { // this line added

// Clear screen with black color
canvas.drawRGB(0, 0, 0);

// Draw line
if(startDrawLine) {

    // Set properties to Paint object
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);

    // Draw path
    path.moveTo(touchDownX, touchDownY);

    for(Point point: points) {
        path.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }
    path.reset();
}

} // this line added
```

Comment: I guess the list has to be modifying while I'm touching my finger and store the point and at the same time iterating the list to be able to draw the line!? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Yes I'm using SurfaceView, but what should I synchronize?

Comment: @3D-kreativ If you are not doing complex computations (and doesn't look like you do) to draw things, I'd suggest extending `View` and `onDraw` instead of complicating things for now. You will have no problems with synchronization. But if you want to stick with `SurfaceView` - just wrap all access to points variable with `synchronize (...) { }` block.

Comment: Hmm, this was hard to understand! Should I use synchronize(.... in front the above code: if(startDrawLine) {..... ??

Comment: Thanks for the added code! Now it's works, but it slow down the rest of the moving objects on the canvas to much! What could be the reason for this? And I thought that SurfaceView was better to use than just View, why not use this for production? It's hard to know what is bad and what is good! How should I do to improve my code?

Comment: You may try to add `SystemClock.sleep(1);` in the place you call `drawObjects` or as a first line in `drawObjects` before synchornization to let main thread have some CPU to handle user events. But that's like reinventing the wheel. I've never created games with a lot of calculations in Android and so didn't use `SurfaceView`. For a chess game which doesn't need more than 25 FPS `View` is ok. You could try to find some article on game developement.